# How can I print as strings the content of a .txt file?

Tags: c, string, file, pointers

Like I said in the title I don't know how to print all the content of a .txt file in C.
Here's an incomplete function that I did:

```
void
print_from_file(items_t *ptr,char filemane[25]){
char *string_temp;
FILE *fptr;
fptr=fopen(filemane, "r");
if(fptr){
    while(!feof(fptr)){

        string_temp=malloc(sizeof(char*));
        fscanf(fptr,"\n %[a-z | A-Z | 0-9/,.€#*]",string_temp);
        printf("%s\n",string_temp);
        string_temp=NULL;

    }
}
fclose(fptr);
```

}

I'm pretty sure that there's errors in the fscanf because sometimes it doesn't exit the loop.

Can anyone please correct this?

Comment: Your `string_temp=malloc(sizeof(char*));` You're allocating memory in the size of a char pointer to your string_temp. malloc itself returns a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `malloc` wrong. Passing `sizeof(char*)` to `malloc` means you are only giving your string the amount of memory it would take to hold a pointer to a character(array). So currently, by writing into memory you have not allocated, you have undefined behavior. It is also highly advisable to perform checks on file lenght and otherwise make sure that you do not write more into the string then you allocated to it.

Instead, do something like this:

```
    string_temp=malloc(100*sizeof(char)); // Enough space for 99 characters (99 chars + '\0' terminator)
```

Comment: Thanks you, I just fixed that! But it doesn't exit the while loop

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to fix in your code.
First of all, you should always check if a file has been opened correctly.

Example:

```
FILE *fp; //file pointer

if((fp = fopen("file.txt", "r") == NULL) {    //check opening

printf("Could not open file");  //or use perror()

exit(0); 

}
```

Also, remember that scanf() and fscanf() return the number of elements they have read. So, for example, if you scan the file one word at a time, you could simplify your program by looping while fscanf(..) == 1.

As a final note, remember to allocate dynamic memory correctly.
You do not want to allocate memory based on a pointer to char size, in fact, you're gonna wanna allocate 1 byte for each character of the string, + 1 for the terminator.

Example:

```
char name[55];
char * name2;

//To make them of the same size:

name2 = malloc(sizeof(*char)); **WRONG**
name2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 55); //OK
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, now I understand that i was allocating the memory for a pointer and not for a string. I've alredy check if the file has been opened correctly using if(fptr){

Comment: Do you know what's the problem in the while loop? Because it doesn't exit from the loop